# Is the real coordinate space in polar coordinates the same as the real coordinate system for the plane?

Tags: general-topology

I understand one could transition from one to the other but I would like to know if they are the same two dimensional space. Why I ask?

In a topology book I am reading  the polar coordinates can be represented as one dimensional verticle lines from 0 to pi and map from one plane to another plane. Whereas the polar coordinate plane has a different visualization of concentric rings expanding outward.

Maybe a subtle point but I would like to ask.

Comment: A coordinate system is a mapping from points in the plane ($\Bbb R^2$) to some set of pairs of numbers:each point gets a pair of numbers and these are its coordinates.  For polar coordinates, it's the same plane, but it's a different set of pairs of numbers, and it's a different mapping.

Comment: @MJD . got it thank you

Comment: There is no such thing as a coordinate space.

Comment: @William Elliot. Thank you.  I fixed it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, cartesian and polar coordinates account for the same space, just different notation. Every point on a cartesian plane can be represented with a polar coordinate and vice versa. However, due to the way angles work, there are infinitely many ways to represent one distinct point with polar coordinates, if you allow the range of the angle to be all real numbers.

For example: the point (1,1) on a cartesian plane is the polar point $(\sqrt2, (\pi+n2\pi)/4)$ where n is any integer.